# Why does my comparator not work after first loop?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a pretty simple `If Else` statement in my code that looks like this:

```
If GUI.editedFH = "" Then
    fhNumField.Value = fhNumField.List(0)
Else
    fhNumField.Value = editedFH
End If
```

This block of code is in a `UserForm_Initialize()` sub that I call fairly often after users use the form to edit or delete rows of data. I unload the form and reload it as a way to "refresh" the data presented in the form.

The code fails at the first line in that `If` statement. VBE throws this error

```
Run-time error '1004':
Application-defined or object-defined error
```

`GUI.editedFH` is a global string that is declared in a separate module. `GUI` is the name of the module, and `editedFH` is the string variable name. I put a watch on `GUI.editedFH` and I'm getting `String` as the type and the value that I want.

When I hardcode string values in, instead of `GUI.editedFH`, it still doesn't work i.e.

```
If "abc" = "" Then
    '....
End If
```

The part that is most confusing is that I can compare strings like this elsewhere, and it is seemingly random on when the error will throw. It will work the first time through the initialize and a few subsequent times, but eventually it will throw an error.

Comment: Don't think you can have a variable with a `.` in it.

Comment: "it still doesn't work" - does that mean it throws the same 1004 error?

Comment: I don't know how you are available -not trying to be rude, it's just strange for me that Excel is not showing it- to code those variables without getting a horrible red "expected end of statement" warning in vba when you use special characters so it wouldn't let you even get to run the code in 1st place.

Comment: I would have guessed that, somehow, your GUI object dropped out of scope, even though it's global. But if the `"abc" = ""` comparison throws an error then you're in stranger danger. Can you generate a simplified example that would allow us to replicate the problem?

Comment: You need to show variable declaration. What are `GUI` and `fhNumField` dimmed as & what do they contain?

Comment: @findwindow @Sgdva @Vegard `GUI` is a different module and `editedFH` is a global string that is declared in the `GUI` module. I've used that `Module.variable` notation all throughout my code just fine

Comment: @OldUgly I'm working on trying to reproduce the error but it seems like a tricky one to pin down